# I need some help with doing a RewriteBase for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently got an arcade script through a membership site that I belong to. The owner of the site offered free install of the script. I registered a domain name and got a hosting account with godaddy.com The script was installed, but I am having a slight problem. Everything else seems to be working fine, except for clicking on the links on the left hand menu that says "Categories".

Here is my site: http://www.freeonlinegamerooms.com

I called GoDaddy customer service and was advised that I needed to add a Rewrite Base to my .htaccess file . They sent me a link to the apache site, but it hasn't helped me at all, as I am a non-technical person. It's all Greek to me. The guy who installed my script has tried to get it fixed, to no avail. He said he isn't a progammer either. Here is the text of my .htaccess file, as it presently exists:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "^game/([0-9]+)/$" file.php?id=$1 [Last]
RewriteRule "^category/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$" category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [Last]
```

Can anyone help me with this, please? All I want is a site that works properly. I am sure this something very easy for a programmer to figure out, I'm just at a loss myself because I'm not a programmer.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a slash in the rewrite rule after the ^.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "^/game/([0-9]+)/$" file.php?id=$1 [Last]
RewriteRule "^/category/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$" category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [Last]
```

edit: this is **wrong**, see my follow-up comment in this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that but it didn't work, I still got the 404 Error. The slash before 'game' or 'category' would indicate that it was a folder/directory, wouldn't it? The whole thing is, there's no folder for either of them.. The way the guy who installed it for me explained it was like this:

Comment: Hey Doug,
 
The games are in the /files folder. If you look you also see that there is no /category folder.
 
If you hover over the Action link in the left menu you'll see that it points to http://www.freeonlinegamerooms.com/category/103/1/ so at first glance you might think "hey that's the problem, there is no category folder so I that's why I am getting a 404 error.
 
The way the script works is that when you click on that link, it pulls the info from the database and then makes temporary link to http://www.freeonlinegamerooms.com/category/103/1/

Comment: If the script didn't handle it like that you would have to actually have a folder called "category" and that folder would have to contain the information for all of the games and what category they were in. This would make it a big problem if you want to add (or delete) a game or another category. You would have to manually edit all of the information. That's why we use databases and scripts.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now. You have it correct in your question. If you will, you can add a `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine on`, but it works well without it. The problem seems to be that the server is configured to skip .htaccess configuration. If you have access to the configuration of the server, you need to change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` in this VirtualHost section.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos. I have contacted GoDaddy to find out how to change the configuration, as I couldn't find anything in the control panel for the hosting account. I did find something to set up SymLinks, but I don't know how to do that, either. There weren't any set up, although the .htaccess file does say Follow SymLinks. Any ideas on this? Thanks again for your time and patience.